# Add a note to system config page?

Tags: magento-1.7, system.xml

I've created an option under System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog that allows an admin to select which customer groups can add products to the cart. I now want to notify admin's about this setting when they are changing wishlist settings on another system config page. Something like "Products in the Wishlist can only be added to the cart if blah blah blah."

1) I know about the `<depends>` tag, but I don't know how to use that for settings from other parts of the config. For instance `<depends><active>1</active></depends>` is simple, but how can I do that for fields from other groups or sections?

2) Is there a standardized way to put a notification or simple string on a system config page, or does Magento only support fields out of the box?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to the "comment" node of a system.xml field or group? That's the "static" way of adding a description string to a config field. You want something more dynamic?

Comment: I'm not looking to add a comment to a single field exactly, just text on it's own line without a new field to go with it.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure if this answers the second part of your question or not but you can add a `comment` node on fields and also on groups so that each group could contain a comment. As explained by [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations)

> comment you can add your own comment to a field or group